# How do I set extent in a geopandas plot (as in cartopy)?

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, cartopy

The usual. My shapefile is from a much bigger place than my data, and I want to zoom in. The dark dot below is Melbourne, and it has some very interesting data plotted on it.

[image]

```
base.plot(linewidth=0
     ,color='gray'
     ,alpha=.1
     ,ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 4):

I had forgotten to use the `cartopy` projection, which sets the `.set_extent` property in the `matplotlib` axis.

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

extent = (b['x coordinate'].min(), b['x coordinate'].max(), b['y coordinate'].min(), b['y coordinate'].max())

ax = plt.axes([0, 0, 1, 1],
                projection=ccrs.LambertCylindrical())
ax.set_extent(extent, ccrs.LambertCylindrical())

cols = ['x coordinate','y coordinate', 'div_name','div_code']
dd = d[cols]
dd.columns = ['long','lat', 'div_name','div_code']
educ = dd.loc[dd.div_code == 'P']
retail = dd.loc[dd.div_code == 'G']
ax = sns.kdeplot(educ.long, educ.lat,
                cmap="Reds", n_levels=5, shade=False, shade_lowest=False, plot_kws={'alpha':0.3}, ax=ax)
sns.kdeplot(retail.long, retail.lat,
                cmap="Blues", n_levels=5, shade=False, shade_lowest=False, plot_kws={'alpha':0.3}, ax=ax)

base.plot(linewidth=0
        ,color='gray'
        ,alpha=.1
        ,ax=ax)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `set_xlim()` and `set_ylim()` methods in `matplotlib` are sufficient to set the extent of the map.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

xlim = ([2.2E6, 7.5E6])
ylim = ([1.3E6, 5.5E6])

ax.set_xlim(xlim)
ax.set_ylim(ylim)

countries = gpd.read_file("CountryBorders.geojson")

countries.plot(column="population", legend=True, ax=ax)
```